# Print variable value in Python Tkinter Label

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to print a `n_clusters_` variable in a label, but it's not updating. The computation of `n_clusters_` is in another class. But I already set it as global variable. This is the code:

```
class nCluster():
    def __init__(self):
        label = Label(LabelHasil, text="Jumlah cluster yang ditemukan : ")
        label.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    def n_cluster(self):
        cluster_label = Label(LabelHasil, textvariable=n_clusters_)
        cluster_label.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
show_n_cluster = nCluster()
```

This is the class where `n_clusters_` is computed:

```
class Proses:
    def __init__(self):
        button = Button(window, text="Proses", command=lambda: stdbscan(self), width=10)
        button.pack()
    def stdbscan(self):
         ...
        global n_clusters_
        n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0) 
show_proses = Proses()
```

I need to print `n_clusters_` variable whenever it's updated. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you define `nCluster.n_cluster` which should create and pack your label, but never call it. This doesn't actually need to be in its own method, either, just toss it in at the end of `nCluster.__init__`.

The big problem is you need to make `n_clusters_` a `tkinter.StringVar` so that it updates properly.

```
class Proses:
     ...
    def stdbscan(self):
     ...
    global n_clusters_
    n_clusters_ = StringVar()
    n_clusters_.set( len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0) )
```